# How to display video in a slider

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe, jwplayer

I am using galleria slider as a jquery slider nd jwplayer to display videos. Problem is that it does not display the jwplayer in the slider, it just displays a black square. I got it working for images but can't get it working for the video player jwplayer. Can somebody who knows how to do this modify the code below so it is working in my app?

Galleria: http://galleria.io/docs/

jwplayer: http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/

```
<?php if(count($arrVideoFile[$key]) > 1){ ?>
    <style>
        #galleriavideo_<?php echo $key; ?>{ width: 500px; height: 300px; background: #000 }
    </style>
    <div id="galleriavideo_<?php echo $key; ?>">
        <?php foreach ($arrVideoFile[$key] as $v) { ?>
            <div id="myElement-<?php echo $key.'-'.$i; ?>">Loading the player...
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jwplayer("myElement-<?php echo $key.'-'.$i; ?>").setup({
                        file: "<?php echo 'VideoFiles/'.$v; ?>",
                        width: 480,
                        height: 270
                    });
                    <?php $i++; ?>
                </script> 
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>      
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Galleria.loadTheme('jquery/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
        Galleria.run('#galleriavideo_<?php echo $key; ?>');  
    </script>   
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Don; follow the question, but you can't have two "id" the same in an HTML page. So "id='addtd'" may give you problems. (It may also be the bit you want to change, to be unique, but I'm not 100% sure, so can't put it as an answer.

Comment: A duplicate of the [already asked many times too localized question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199379/how-to-associate-each-option-button-with-their-own-individual-marks)

Comment: My apologies, i change question

Comment: @user1394925 If you press F12 on your web browser, do you receive any errors in the "Console" tab? F12 should open up your "developer tools" in most web browsers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a bit strange, another user posted an extremely similar question here: [Having trouble using iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883914/having-trouble-using-iframes)

Anyway, I will try to post a solution close to your code. I presume you want **one slider with multiple videos**.

You need two files: `video.php`, a page showing a video according to a certain filename and `gallery.php`, the page containing the slider.

`video.php`:

```
<?php
    $v = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "v", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
?>

<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("container").setup({
        file: "VideoFiles/<?php echo $v; ?>",
        width: 480,
        height: 270
    });
</script>
```

`gallery.php`:

```
<?php if(count($arrVideoFile[$key]) > 1){ ?>

     <div id="galleriavideo" style="width:500px; height:300px; background:#000;">
         <?php
             foreach($arrVideoFile[$key] as $v) { 
                 $vurl = "/path/to/video.php?v=".rawurlencode($v);?>
                 <a href="<?php echo $vurl; ?>"><img class="iframe"></a>
         <?php } ?> 
     </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/galleria.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Galleria.loadTheme('/path/to/galleria.classic.min.js');
        Galleria.run('#galleriavideo');
    </script>

<?php } ?>
```