# Having trouble using iframes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am failing badly when it comes to using iframes and I need some help. I have never used an iframe before, this is my first time.

Here is a doucment on what I am trying to follow to produce an iframe with the galleria slider: http://galleria.io/docs/references/data/

What I have is a jwplayer and I want to access a video(s) using an iframe to retrieve the videos which are in the `video.php` page. If there is a single video, then simply retrieve the correct video from the video.php page but if there are multiple videos, then retrieve the correct multiple videos and display them in the galleria slider. But my question is how can I get the iframe to work in order to do this?

Below is the video.php page where it displays the jwplayer:

```
   <div id="myElement-<?php echo $key.'-'.$i; ?>">Loading the player...

    <script type="text/javascript">


    jwplayer("myElement-<?php echo $key.'-'.$i; ?>").setup({
        file: "<?php echo 'VideoFiles/'.$v; ?>",
        width: 480,
        height: 270
    });

    <?php $i++; ?>
```

Below is the code where it checks if the video is a single or multiple, displays the galleria slider if multiple and this is where the iframe is placed:

```
if(count($arrVideoFile[$key]) == 1){
    foreach ($arrVideoFile[$key] as $v) { ?>

var data = [
    {

     iframe: 'video.php'

     }
];  


<?php
}
}else if(count($arrVideoFile[$key]) > 1){
?>

<style>
    #galleriavideo_<?php echo $key; ?>{ width: 500px; height: 300px; background: #000 }
</style>

 <div id="galleriavideo_<?php echo $key; ?>">
<?php
foreach ($arrVideoFile[$key] as $v) { ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

var data = [
    {

     iframe: 'video.php'

     }
];
</script>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>

         <script type="text/javascript">

            Galleria.loadTheme('jquery/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
            Galleria.run('#galleriavideo_<?php echo $key; ?>');

          </script>

<?php

        }
    }
        //end:procedure video
```

**EDIT:
video.php**

```
<?php

$key = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "key", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$i = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "i", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$v = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "v", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

?>
<div id="myElement-<?php echo $key.'-'.$i; ?>">Loading the player...

<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("myElement-<?php echo $key.'-'.$i; ?>").setup({
    file: "<?php echo 'VideoFiles/'.$v; ?>",
    width: 480,
    height: 270
});

</script>

</div>
```

**assessment.php:**

```
if(count($arrVideoFile[$key]) > 1){
?>

<style>
    #galleriavideo_<?php echo $key; ?>{ width: 500px; height: 300px; background: #000 }
</style>

 <div id="galleriavideo_<?php echo $key; ?>">
<?php
foreach ($arrVideoFile[$key] as $v) { ?>

<a href="video.php?key={$key}&i={$i}&v={$v}"><img class="iframe"></a>

<?php $i++; ?>
<?php } ?>
</div>

         <script type="text/javascript">

            Galleria.loadTheme('jquery/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
            Galleria.run('#galleriavideo_<?php echo $key; ?>');

          </script>

<?php

        }
```

Comment: what iframes? there are none in your code.

Comment: @MarcB I am using it in the javascript, I have never used iframe before so I have no clue on how it is implemented, if I can see a sample, especially a sample for above example then I can see how an iframe is implemented and be able to refer to it for future use

Comment: @user2056342 If its your first time with iFrames i would look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short example on how to use Galleria with jwplayer. You can try to adapt it to your code then.

First, there is the `video.php` file which contains the jwplayer:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("container").setup({
        file: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/3XnJSIm4-kNspJqnJ.mp4",
        image: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/thumbs/3XnJSIm4-640.jpg"
    });
</script>
```

Then, there is the `gallery.php` file, which contains the slider:

```
<div id="galleria" style="height:350px; width:550px;">
    <a href="/path/to/video.php"><img class="iframe"></a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/galleria.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Galleria.loadTheme('/path/to/galleria.classic.min.js');
    Galleria.run('#galleria');
</script>
```

If you want to display multiple videos in the slider, you can imagine a solution where `video.php` takes a parameter and loads a video according to it, i.e. `video.php?id=xx`

**Edit:** to clarify a bit

Your `video.php`file should take some parameters:

```
$key = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "key", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$i = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "i", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$v = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "v", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

<div id="myElement-<?php echo $key.'-'.$i; ?>">Loading the player...
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("myElement-<?php echo $key.'-'.$i; ?>").setup({
    file: "<?php echo 'VideoFiles/'.$v; ?>",
    width: 480,
    height: 270
});
```

And then in the `gallery.php` file:

```
<div id="galleria" style="height:350px; width:550px;">
    <a href="/path/to/video.php?key=xxx&i=xxx&v=xxx"><img class="iframe"></a>
    <a href="/path/to/video.php?key=xxx&i=xxx&v=xxx"><img class="iframe"></a>
    <a href="/path/to/video.php?key=xxx&i=xxx&v=xxx"><img class="iframe"></a>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: It is the file: in the video.php I do not understand. If it is multiple videos is it suppose to be `file: <?php echo $key; ?>`?

Comment: @user2056342 I edited my answer to show you what would `video.php` be.

Comment: Hi, thanks only one issue and that is what are xxx suppose to be?

Comment: These would be variables you have in your code: `<a href="/path/to/video.php?key={$key}&i={$i}&v={$v}`

Comment: It is displaying slider but unable to find the video. Is there anything else I need to add? Code in edit in question

Comment: These were PHP variables, and you put them into HTML code: they are not interpreted. Try with this: `<a href="/path/to/video.php?key=<?php echo $key; ?>}&i=<?php echo $i; ?>&v=<?php echo $v; ?>"><img class="iframe"></a>`